# latest jquery ui no longer support datepicker select by year?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker

Good day,

In my old jQuery, my datepicker is allow to select by year, I checked the code, its control by a jQuery css class call `ui-datepicker-new-year`. This class is located at `ui.datepicker.css`, and being call in `ui.datetimepicker.min.js`.

Its look like this:
[image]

I upgrade my jQuery version to 1.12.1. And found that the class `ui-datepicker-new-year` no longer exists in the jquery-ui.js and jquery-ui.css file. Thus, my datepicker no longer can select by year like above picture.

Would like to ask, is it any other ways that I can call the year selection in the latest jQuery UI? Or the latest jQuery UI no longer support year selection?

Comment: [jQuery UI Documentation: Datepicker - Display month & year menus](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year), which would suggest that it still works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this to show change year dropdown

```
$("#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
});
```